# How to use the free domain given by ngrok?

Tags: python, django, flask, ngrok

In their release of ngrok https://ngrok.com/blog-post/new-ngrok-domains, they now provide free domains to free users as of April 2023. I can see my one free domain at https://dashboard.ngrok.com/cloud-edge/domains. However, I don't know how to use it.

I have tried
`ngrok http -subdomain=xxx.ngrok-free.app 80`
and
`ngrok http -subdomain=xxx 80`

But it will give me an error

```
Custom subdomains are a feature on ngrok's paid plans.
Failed to bind the custom subdomain 'xxx.ngrok-free.app' for the account 'James Arnold'.
This account is on the 'Free' plan.
```

Is there a documentation on how to use this free domain by ngrok?

Comment: Did you update the client? The same article mentions that the `--subdomain` flag is deprecated…

Comment: @deceze I am running in google colab so every run, the `pip install` is always executed. Do you know what the exact command is for my case?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are expericing occured when auth token is not added in config or env,

I didn't bind my ngrok with django app but here I did the same for nodejs application running on linux server, so here are the steps I followed you can take reference from it:

Step:1 Install ngrok and set up auth token(https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken) in config file (in my case it is saved in /home/user/.config/mgrok/ngrok.yml) as shown below:

```
snap install ngrok

ngrok config add-authtoken {{your-auth-token}}
```

Step:2 Bind ngrok custom domain tunnel with your application port as shown below

```
ngrok http --domain=mycustom-domain-quagga.ngrok-free.app 5000
```

In Step:2 I have set the port to 5000 since my node.js application is running on port 5000

Answer (score 0):

I work at ngrok, we do indeed now support free static domains. Did you claim your domain? It's in the yellow banner. Otherwise I can help you, sam at ngrok.com

Comment: Yes. I have a domain in my https://dashboard.ngrok.com/cloud-edge/domains. I just don't know how to use it.